# How to decrypt string in nodejs that encrypted in php with aes-128-cbc algorithm?

Tags: php, node.js, encryption

I need to encrypt string, send http request with this encrypted string and then decrypt it in nodejs server.

Php side:

```
$var  = openssl_encrypt('string', "aes-128-cbc", 'stringstringstri');
```

Nodejs side:

```
let decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-cbc', 'stringstringstri');
let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'utf8', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
```

also tried

```
const initVector = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', 'stringstringstri', initVector)
let decryptedData = decipher.update(encrypted, 'utf8', 'utf-8')
decryptedData += decipher.final('utf-8');
```

and recieved error:
`wrong final block length` or `this[kHandle].initiv(cipher, credential, iv, authTagLength); TypeError: Invalid initialization vector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not passing any `iv` in PHP, it used the default `iv` which is an empty string. Hence, you need to consider this in Node.js as well.

So the changes would be like this:

```js
const key = 'string';
const cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, Buffer.alloc(16));
const cipherEncrypted = Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64');
const decrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(cipherEncrypted), cipher.final()]);
console.log(decrypted.toString());
```

Comment: I tried this snippet, but changed yours 'aes-128-ecb' to 'aes-128-cbc'
key: elonmuskelonmusk

and recieved error: Invalid initialization vector

Comment: @ChumachenkoMihail My bad, I thought you asked about `aes-128-ecb`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks to you, man! You're really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Could you implement something like this post suggest?
https://ashish-dhodare.medium.com/implementing-aes-cbc-encryption-in-node-js-java-and-c-cross-language-encryption-42d1844119b9

````
function encrypt(plainString, AesKey, AesIV) {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-cbc", AesKey, AesIV);
    let encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(Buffer.from(plainString, "utf8")), cipher.final()]);
    return encrypted.toString("base64");
}

function decrypt(base64String, AesKey, AesIV) {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-cbc", AesKey, AesIV);
    const deciphered = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(Buffer.from(base64String, "base64")), decipher.final()]);
    return deciphered.toString("utf8");
}

// const key = crypto.randomBytes(32); //Need 32 bytes (256 bits) key as we are using AES-256 encryption
const key = Buffer.from("J/PYjc1ftDFK5+77U1PB80v2TamokGap5yCIP2YI6tQ=", "base64");
// const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); //Need 16 bytes (128 bits) Initialization vector as default block size is 128 bits
const iv = Buffer.from("gaOr3uvhZEwFeSbRHwlHcg==", "base64");

// Its better to pass iv and key in bytes/buffer
var encryptedData = encrypt("some data to encrypt", key, iv);
console.log(encryptedData);
// Need same key and iv for decryption otherwise it won't work
var decryptedData = decrypt(encryptedData, key, iv)
console.log(decryptedData);```
````

Comment: I tried to copy your code with no changes, but it doesn't work((
also i tried to replace key string with 16 charcters, same result

Error:
``` 
    this[kHandle].initiv(cipher, credential, iv, authTagLength);
   RangeError: Invalid key length
```